# iphone - a different name for Default.png

Tags: iphone

I am creating this new version of one of my apps and this new version has a new interface. As I am on the testing phase, I am building the app using a different target on Xcode I wonder if there's a way to tell the target to use another file name for the loading image, instead of just "Default.png"?

Don't tell me it is not possible... :(

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually very simple. In the Info.plist file for your new target, add the UILaunchImageFile key and set it to the basename of your file. Then, include your new default image instead of Default.png in your build process. If you want more information, go to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html. The section on launch images is about halfway down the page.

Comment: brilliant!!!!!!! What amazes me is that Apple scatters information about docs. Their page that talks about Default.png says it has to be named that way. No mention to this key. This is why I hate apple docs. Your solution is brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple files named Default.png, each in a separate subdirectory, and include them all in one Project.  Then, for each Target in the Project, click the include checkbox for just the one Default.png file you want included in the build for that Target, and uncheck any other's if necessary.  If you make any changes, do a Clean before you Build.

Comment: Definitely possible. hotpaw2 got it right. you can also do it with preprocessor macros.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, not possible. A work around would be to start with no and/or a black Default.png and add your own UIImageView in `applicationDidFinishLoading:`.

Not ideal but might help for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I was suspecting it was not possible. Strangely, you can define your own icon name but not the loading image... thanks anyway.